# Unable to configure EAV setup resource

Tags: magento

I'm trying to create a EAV module and I got stuck in here for a very long time.

error msg :

```
    Invalid entity_type specified: gagan_eavfaq

#0 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Config.php(328): Mage::throwException('Invalid entity_...')
#1 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php(276): Mage_Eav_Model_Config->getEntityType('gagan_eavfaq')
#2 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\code\local\Gagan\Eavfaq\Model\Resource\Eav\Mysql4\Eavfaq.php(9): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->setType('gagan_eavfaq')
#3 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Abstract.php(44): Gagan_Eavfaq_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Eavfaq->_construct()
#4 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract->__construct(Array)
#5 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('eavfaq_mysql4/e...', Array)
#6 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\Mage.php(490): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('eavfaq/eavfaq', Array)
#7 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\Mage.php(518): Mage::getResourceModel('eavfaq/eavfaq', Array)
#8 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(139): Mage::getResourceSingleton('eavfaq/eavfaq')
#9 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(225): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_getResource()
#10 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\code\local\Gagan\Eavfaq\controllers\IndexController.php(8): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(1)
#11 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(419): Gagan_Eavfaq_IndexController->indexAction()
#12 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#13 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 C:\wamp\www\www.ubt.com\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

Config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Gagan_eavfaq>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Gagan_eavfaq>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <eavfaq>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Gagan_Eavfaq</module>
                    <frontName>eavfaq</frontName>
                </args>
            </eavfaq>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

    <global>
        <models>
            <eavfaq>
                <class>Gagan_Eavfaq_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>eavfaq_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </eavfaq>
            <eavfaq_mysql4>
                <class>Gagan_Eavfaq_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <dinkchika>
                        <table>gagan_eavfaq</table>
                    </dinkchika>
                </entities>
            </eavfaq_mysql4>
        </models>

       <resources>
            <eavfaq_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Gagan_Eavfaq</module>
                  <class>Gagan_Eavfaq_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </eavfaq_setup>
        <eavfaq_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </eavfaq_write>
        <eavfaq_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </eavfaq_read>
        </resources>  

    </global>        
</config>
```

Resource :

```
    <?php

class Gagan_Eavfaq_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Eavfaq
extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract
{

    public function _construct() {
        $resource = mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $this->setType('gagan_eavfaq');
        $this->setConnection(
                $resource->getConnection('eavfaq_read'),
                $resource->getConnection('eavfaq_write')
                );
    }
}
```

setup :

```
    <?php

class Gagan_Eavfaq_Entity_Setup extends
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup{

}
```

**install script:**
*I want this exception to show. It looks like my setup is not finding a way to this file, from this I can conclude something is wrong with my config. But I've checked that several time still no luck. Please help. Thank you*

```
    <?php   $installer = $this;
throw new Exception("set up configured ");
```

folder structure:

[image]

Comment: You haven't followed the tutorial properly, at first glance there is one more than one thing in what you have shown above that is either different or missing.  For instance, you haven't defined your `eavfaq_read` and `eavfaq_write` resources but you reference them, and the entity setup class doesn't even have the `getDefaultEntities()` method (which by the way is what is causing your immediate error).  I would follow the tutorial again and make sure you actually understand it which it looks like you probably don't at the moment.

Comment: no getDefaultEntities() is the next step.